# Storing multiple radio button data

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I want to have radio buttons that tell my information where it should be displayed on certain pages, but I am unsure of how to store that information in the mySQL database.  Can I just make 2 fields called "Page" and "Section" and separate each value with a comma and have PHP read that back at the time so it knows where to display the information on the page?  IF so, how can this be done?

Any other suggestions are appreciated to make this simpler!

Comment: what does your form look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much simpler than you probably think it is.

Have the radio buttons share a name, but have different values.

```
<input type="radio" name="some_var" value="one" />
<input type="radio" name="some_var" value="two" />
```

Then, on the PHP side, the variable $_REQUEST['some_var'] will contain the value "one" or "two" according to whichever is selected. (If neither is selected, the variable will not exist in $_REQUEST.)

From that point on, write to database like any other text field.

Comment: Let me refine my question to this:  I use "radio buttons" and "checkbox" as the same term, so sorry for the mixup.  What I want to know is how I can the user can select 2 or more checkboxes and store them in a database field because I have not clue how many the user will check off.  Maybe an alternate solution would be to just to write PHP code to add another field to the database.

Comment: Ah, you might want to open up a new question, then. :) Also you might want to provide some code to give a better context of what you're trying to achieve.